# Accessing non-port80 web server using IPv6

Tags: firefox, ipv6, ports

In a normal IPv4 network, I can go into any browser such as Firefox and browse a server on a IPv4 address not hosted on port 80:

```
http://192.168.42.6:8080/
```

This accesses the server on port 8080 on `192.168.42.6`. However, if I try this with a IPv6 IP, I get no luck. This tries to access port 8080 on `fe80::520:ff0f:ece0:1` :

```
http://[fe80::520:ff0f:ece0:1]:8080/
```

Firefox will automatically "fix" this URL to:

```
http://[www.fe80::520:ff0f:ece0:1.com]:8080/
```

which does not help me access it at all. So either I am doing something really wrong OR there's something really wrong with IPv6. Couldn't find anything that even remotely helped on the Internet. (And yes, there is a server running on the IPv6 in question.)

Comment: Do other browsers do similar things?

Comment: Seems like only Firefox does this - IE8 on Windows 7 doesn't, but switching to IE for the entire organization is not an option.

Comment: Then maybe it's just a Firefox bug. What version of Firefox are you using? The current 4.0 beta doesn't seem to do this, at least on my system.

Comment: Is IPv6 disabled in the about:config page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: I am no IPv6 expert.

If you cannot add a DNS name (or want to ensure IPv6 is used<sup>1</sup>), then why not use the actual address, rather than the `fe80` link-local one? On a Mac with OS X, and on Windows XP Home edition, this (with an actual IPv6 address<sup>2</sup>) works fine for me, in all browsers:

```
http://[2001:db8::216:cbff:xx:xx]:8080/
```

(Note that some browsers do not automatically prefix the `http://` part for IPv6 addresses. Adding a dummy name in your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) for *only* the IPv6 address makes life even easier.)

For `fe80` addresses, it's probably not just the port number that is giving you problems; when using the default port 80, you probably cannot connect either, *unless* you also specify the zone index. (Thus: the outgoing interface that should make the connection, like wired ethernet or wireless, which might be different on each computer you use.)

On Windows XP Home edition, with both wired ethernet and wireless (the latter being inactive), the following works fine for me in Firefox 3.5 and 3.6. Here, `4` is my network interface index<sup>3</sup>:

```
http://[fe80::216:cbff:xx:xx%4]/
http://[fe80::216:cbff:xx:xx%4]:8080/
```

In Internet Explorer 8, the percent character must be [percent-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) into `%25`:

```
http://[fe80::216:cbff:xx:xx%254]:8080/
```

(For me, this does not work without the `%4` or `%254`; if it does on other installations then maybe Windows or IE prefers *external* connections, and that installation only has a single network interface?)

On a Mac, the following works fine in Firefox:

```
http://[fe80::216:cbff:xx:xx%en0]:8080/
```

Specifying a zone index using the percent notation is troublesome, given [the conflict with URL notations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Link-local_addresses_and_zone_indices)<sup>4</sup>. I could not get the above to work in Chrome 8 and 9 on Windows XP, nor in Safari or Chrome on a Mac.

On a Mac, instead of the `%` syntax, you can (ab)use the scope index (the 2nd word, or 3rd and 4th bytes) to specify the network interface index. Like `fe80:0004` works fine in all my browsers:

```
http://[fe80:4::216:cbff:xx:xx]/
http://[fe80:4::216:cbff:xx:xx]:8080/
```

Note, however, that **I doubt this is officially supported**, as this does not work on my Windows XP, and [some documentation](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/ipv6.html#IPV6-SCOPE-INDEX) claims that alternatives should always be used instead. Like:

```
ping6 -I en0 fe80::216:cbff:xx:xx  (en0 = wired ethernet on my Mac)
ping6 fe80::216:cbff:xx:xx%en1     (en1 = wireless)
```

...rather than:

```
ping6 fe80:4::216:cbff:xx:xx
ping6 fe80:6::216:cbff:xx:xx
```

Final note: one might be fooled into using `::` or `::ffff:` followed by an IPv4 address, as specified in [RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.2). But, this does not actually use IPv6, though it gives a response on my Mac:

```
http://[::ffff:192.168.178.25]:8080/
```

This can also use a hexadecimal notation, and some browsers will rewrite it automatically:

```
http://[::ffff:c0a8:b219]:8080/
```

But no matter what: this uses an IPv4 connection on my Macs. On my Macs, `[::192.168.178.25]` does not work. I could not get any form to work on Windows XP.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Some browsers prefer IPv4 over IPv6. See [test-ipv6.com](http://test-ipv6.com). This also is platform dependent.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> In IPv6, web servers might [see the MAC address of your computer](https://superuser.com/questions/54844/can-a-mac-address-be-traced/54863#54863), being `216:cbff:xx:xx` in these examples. I'd rather not publish this super cookie on the net. See also [How to avoid exposing my MAC address when using IPv6?](https://superuser.com/questions/243669/how-to-avoid-exposing-my-mac-address-when-using-ipv6)</sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup> On a Mac: look for the value for `scopeid` in the output of `ifconfig`. [On Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726952.aspx): see the value for `Idx` in the output of `netsh interface ipv6 show interface`. **I have seen this number change after reboots!**</sup>
<sup><sup>4</sup> It seems this once led to an RFC which never made it out of draft. This draft [proposes](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fenner-literal-zone) to use the plus-character instead, but this does not work on my Macs or Windows XP either.</sup>

Comment: Re footnote #2 - see "privacy addressing".

Comment: Yup, @grawity, I noticed [that extension](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3041) being mentioned in RFCs, but failed to find any related settings in my consumer grade modem/router to allow for that. :-(

Comment: If your network is using IPv6 Autoconfiguration, then the address suffix is chosen by your own PC and this is where you should look for Privacy Addressing too. On Linux, `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr=1`; on Windows it's `netsh inter ipv6 set privacy` (on by default).

Comment: On [a Mac](http://ipv6int.net/systems/mac_os_x-ipv6.html): `sudo sysctl -w net.inet6.ip6.use_tempaddr=1` (default value: 0). After that: `ifconfig` shows two IPv6 addresses; [test-ipv6.com](http://test-ipv6.com) and [ipv6-test.com](http://ipv6-test.com) show the temporary address.