# Is my MAC address public when browsing the Internet?

Tags: mac-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is your MAC address revealed when you hit up a website?](https://superuser.com/questions/114110/is-your-mac-address-revealed-when-you-hit-up-a-website)

Can anybody see my MAC address when I'm on the Internet?

Also, where can I check my MAC address?

Comment: Which MAC?  The most exposed one should just be your Modem (or whatever connects you to your ISP).  Your computer is removed by a step or two typically (Modem --> Router --> Computer)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The MAC-address is part of the Link-Layer in the OSI Network Model. I wont go too deep in here, bottom line is, it's only used for communication in your local network, be it cabled or wireless.
The point at which your computers MAC definitely gets lost is when it passes your router, the router only transmits the IP packet to *"the Internet"*. When connecting to the internet your router will not use your computers, but its own MAC address to forward the packet.
This switcheroo happens on all routing points, so your ISP will take your packet, get the IP packet out and put it into another MAC packet and so on.

However, if you are using IPv6 it might be possible that your IP Address can be [generated using parts](https://superuser.com/a/54863/65379) of your computers MAC address.

The tools to check your MAC (and IP) addresses are different from system to system, note they only show your computers local addresses, not what can be seen on the Internet.
Not sure about Windows, I think it's `ipconfig /all`
For Linux (and OSX) it's `ifconfig`

Comment: You're correct, ipconfig /all does it on Windows.

Answer (score 10):

Nobody can see your MAC address on the Internet. Only people on the same LAN as you can see your MAC address. (That sometimes includes people sharing WiFi with you.)

Comment: People don't necessarily have to share the WiFi, MAC addresses sent wireless are always visible, as long as in range of course.

Comment: @Informaficker - Actually they do have to transmit it.

Comment: no MAC no communications

Comment: @FiascoLabs that's not true, there is MAC-less communication, although it is not very common afaik.

Comment: @Informaficker - Explain that please. IP addressing depends on ARP to match an IP to a MAC address.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I though there were some devices that did not rely on MAC for IP transfer, as it isn't really needed on a single link connection, but I have not found anything regarding that matter. I am removing this part from my answer.

Comment: @FiascoLabs That is only true on network protocols that use MAC addresses such as Ethernet and WiFi. There are lots of other ways to exchange IP traffic.